# How to simulate out parameter in C

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a linked list in C, and I have the following problem. My nodes are defined as so:

```
struct node_t {
    void* element;
    node_t* previous;
    node_t* next;
};

struct linkedlist_t {
    node_t* head;
    node_t* tail;
    int length;
};
```

And the method to get an element from the linked list has the following signature:

```
// Gets an element from a linked list.
int linkedlist_get(linkedlist_t* linkedlist, unsigned int index, void* element);
```

Since I need to return an int to signal any error, I went with an out parameter. However, I am not sure how to set the pointer inside the method. I tried doing:

```
element = current->element; // The callee doesn't see it.
*((char*)element) = *((char*)current->element); // Copies only the first char
```

Also, I do not want to copy the element from a memory zone to another, I want both the linkedlist and the callee to reference the same memory zone.

Comment: **Also, I do not want to copy the element from a memory zone to another, I want both the linkedlist and the callee to reference the same memory zone.** That is exactly what poitners are for.

Comment: I know, that's why I had a void*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your get signature should be changed to

```
int linkedlist_get(linkedlist_t* linkedlist, unsigned int index, void** element);
```

Note the extra *.  In the get routine you can then do

```
*element = current->element;
```

Which does what you want.  Obviously this is old style C without any type protections.  Careful of your memory handling.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `void* element`, pass a pointer to `void*` i.e. `void** element`, then set it via

```
*element = current->element;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can instead return the pointer and have the NULL indicate the error state.

```
void* linkedlist_get(linkedlist_t* linkedlist, unsigned int index);

type* p = linkedlist_get(...
if( !p )
{
    //handle error
}
```

This will also has the benefit of having the correct type immediately so you don't have to juggle with void pointers.